# Relative layout android doesn't work correctly

Tags: android, android-layout

Does anyone knows why relative layout is not working and whenever i apply it all the element appear at the top of the layout.

Comment: You should provide more information in order to people help you. That question is pretty vague. What isn't working? Show us the code and tell us what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You have to apply rules for your views inside like

```
android:layout_above
```

Or

```
android:layout_below
```

Check out constraint layout is a new layout where you can set constraints by hand